# lost the database - how do I run dotnet update for all migrations?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

While developing a project I used `dotnet ef migrations add ...` and `dotnet ef database update` to create migrations and populate these changed into the database. I accidently lost the database and (ef does not seem to track the migrations is has applied in the database) cannot get the database to update now.

When I run `dotnet ef database update` it will complain about a missing table. So I thought I would just apply all migrations manually starting with the first one, but it looks like there no initial migration in the `/Migrations` folder so even while applying the first available migration in the `dotnet ef migrations list` I still get `table ... does not exist`.

I lost all my data at this point anyway - how do I perform the 'clean' migration at this point?

Comment: Sounds like you have been deleting files form Migrations folder manually earlier. You should never do that. Always use `dotnet ef database update <previousmigration>` and then `dotnet ef migrations remove` to remove the most recent migration

Comment: No, never removed migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not worried about keeping data you can just delete the database and the migrations folder and then just migrate and update as usual.